# Are there ifdefs in F#?

Tags: f#

I wonder if it possible to run specific code in debug mode.

for example something like this:

```
if DEBUG
 print "Hello World"
```

which only prints "Hello World" if I am in debug mode, but when I am in release mode it should be compiled away. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [compiler directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233195.aspx) for this

```
#if DEBUG
printfn "Hello World"
#endif
```